# Android Add margins programmatically to Webview

Tags: java, android, webview, margins

I need to add margins to a webview programmatically. I would like to do something like below:

```
public void setSideMargin(final int sideMargin, int id) {
    WebView webView = (WebView) ((Activity) context)
            .findViewById(id);

    WebView.LayoutParams p = new WebView.LayoutParams(
            WebView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WebView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    p.leftMargin = sideMargin;
    p.rightMargin = sideMargin;

    webView.setLayoutParams(p);
}
```

This is obviously wrong I know but is there anything like this that I can do to add the margins programmatically? Thanks

Comment: that part `((Activity) context)` is weird, but otherwise I wouldn't say `obviously wrong` in fact that looks about right to me.

Comment: Well it defiantly wrong and the part `((Activity) context)` if because I have the method in a java class so I can reuse it on different activities

Comment: i would probably rather do something like `p = webView.getLayoutParams()` instead of creating one, for starters.

Comment: I've also tried this and have no option to set the margins

Comment: I could set the layout params on the relative view inside it and add padding to the relative view instead of adding margin to the webview? or wrap the webview in a relative layout and add margin to that?

Comment: ok, i see it now. the layoutParams does not depend on the element it is set to, but on the parent. for example, if you put your webview in a linearlayout, you'll get a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. In your case, it is most likely a descendant of `MarginLayoutParam`, so that is what you should cast it to: `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) webView.getLayoutParams()`

Comment: (this is rather counter intuitive, but quite logical on second thought)

Comment: I'm with you, I didn't know that method existed! So by using `MarginLayoutParam` on the webview I can add the margins to it

Comment: Yes, because but only if the parent of the webview (the view it is in) is a viewgroup that supports margins (linearlayout or relativelayout, for example)

Comment: This looks like it will work, I'll debug it now and let you know the results, add it as an answer if you want me to up vote you. Also, instead of using `VIewGroup`, could I not just use RelativeLayout? Is it only ViewGruop because it's more generic to the layout your using?

Comment: Just because `MarginLayoutParams` is originally defined in ViewGroup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The thing to understand with `LayoutParams` is this: The `LayoutParams` does not depend on the element it is set to, but on the parent.

It is an indication given to the parent regarding the positioning of the element.

Therefore, if your `WebView` is in a `LinearLayout`, `getLayoutParams` will get you a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Which means that, in order to have a descendant of `MarginLayoutParam`, a LayoutParams that supports margins, your WebView must be placed in a `ViewGroup` that supports margins, such as `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. (see the list of descendants http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html ). In other words, `WebView` itself does not support margins, its parent does.

In which case, you should cast the `LayoutParams` from the `WebView` to:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) webView.getLayoutParams();
```

Once you have that, you can modify the margins :

```
p.leftMargin = sideMargin;
p.rightMargin = sideMargin;

webView.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: This is perfect and working as expected, Thanks for the help really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
WebView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WebView.LayoutParams) webView.getLayoutParams();
webView.layoutParams.leftMargin = sideMargin;
webView.layoutParams.rightMargin = sideMargin;
webView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

If doesn't work , then take linearlayout parent of this view and insert padding for it.

Example code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) webView.getParent().getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(sideMargin, 0, sideMargin, 0);
((LinearLayout)webView.getParent()).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

2th Example code:

```
LinearLayout webviewLayout = (LinearLayout) webView.getParent();
webviewLayout.setPadding(sideMargin,0,sideMargin,0);
```

Comment: Can't add `LayoutParams` to a webview