# How can i use padding in web view?

Tags: android

> I have following webview, i have no idea how to use padding attribute in webview.

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Doesn't `android:padding="16dp"` work?

Comment: @Sourabh unfortunately not, when loding content in the Webview, it kinda overrides the padding in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> oh i got the solution.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new mWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
            web.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ document.body.style.paddingTop = '55px'})();");
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.137.1/mahen.dev/nrum");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, great solution. I also had the problem that padding was not properly working because after loading actual content in the WebView, it was kinda overwriting the padding. Your solution worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

if your WebView is in a LinearLayout, getLayoutParams will get you a LinearLayout.LayoutParams. use below code:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) webView.getLayoutParams();
p.leftMargin = sideMargin;
p.rightMargin = sideMargin;
webView.setLayoutParams(p);
```

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23520932/5901637)